# Kotlin flatten collections

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of objects of type Range, which in turn has a property which is a list of type List<Map<*, *>>. Now, how do I collect all the elements of this property into a flat list?

```
data class Range(
        @JsonProperty("events") val pEvents: List<Map<*, *>>,
        @JsonProperty("gt_events") val gEvents: List<Map<String, *>>
)
```

How do I traverse ranges to get a list of events and gEvents? Here is something I tried

```
fun processEvents(val ranges: List<Range>):
 val events: List<Map<String, *>> = ranges.flatMap { g -> g.gEvents.map { it } }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're missing here. The code you wrote works, there is just some extra stuff that can be removed. What are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient to get a `List<Map<String, *>>`:

```kotlin
val allGEvents = ranges.flatMap { it.gEvents }
```